# Where is Test folder in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm sorry for such a question but I'm new to IntelliJ (and Gradle, that is used in the project I'm working on), but where exactly is the Test folder located ?

When I display the 'Project structure' window, here's what I can see :

[image]

But what I can really see in the project tree is the following :

[image]

In fact, I don't understand what I see. Do the Test folders exist ?

Can someone tell me how to add a Test folder from the 'Project structure' window and how to say Gradle where test classes are located ?

Thx

Comment: `Gradle` projects have same structure as `Maven` projects. From looks of it, either reimport the project or mark the directory you have shown in the first image as test. Btw, was the project properly imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the Test folders exist ?

No it does not exist on your disk. See the "red" highlighting of the `core/src/test` directory in the project structure on your 1st screenshot.

You can create it from Project tool window. In fact IDE will automatically propose you the directories that you can create according to the [Gradle source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) configuration of your project:

[image]

[image]

See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206806425/comments/360001477800

Comment: Thanx a lot @andrey. With your simple explanations I just see that I completely misunderstood the way Gradle works. It is completely the opposite I tried to do for a few days. Each time I added a test module in the project's tree (on the left side), Gradle used to delete it and I couldn't understand why. I didn't know that it was mandatory to declare it in the build.gradle file to "make it real". That's not the way Maven use to work and I stupidly thought I could use Gradle like Maven.
I passed a lot of time on JetBrain's and Gradle's docs, but your explanation is the best so far. Thx again.